# Installing lxml giving me trouble

Tags: python, cmd, lxml

I've read about this error, but still having no luck getting lxml installed.  Basically, running into this error:

```
  File "L:\Code\Scripts\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  from lxml import etree
  ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Clearly, I need to get the 32 bit installation, but I've tried un-installing lxml and then re-installing the appropriate version, to no avail.

How can I properly install this to avoid this error?  I still do have a file in my directory called etree_lxml.py, could this be the problem? Maybe this needs to be wiped too?

Comment: Have you obtained your installation files from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml? If not, then you should.

Comment: In addition, be sure to verify the checksums on any files downloaded.

Comment: Still is not working/...

Comment: What is checksums?

Comment: And, how do I know which one to download?  None of them seem to be able to be opened by any application on my computer.

Comment: Sorry - for the record, I have lxml-3.4.2 in my scripts folder.