# Trouble installing correct version of lxml (with updated context)

Tags: python, cmd, lxml

I [posted this question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431597/installing-lxml-giving-me-trouble) but have more info, which may be helpful in trying to resolve this issue.  After checking what Python platform I have using:

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
```

It reads:

```
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

I still haven't found a way to get the correct version of lxml, since I'm still getting the error when I import the module, which reads:

```
  File "L:\Code\Scripts\YelpScraper.py", line 1, in <module>
  from lxml import html
  File "L:\Code\Scripts\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  from lxml import etree
  ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

From the advice given here, I've gone to [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) and tried to download the correct version.

The only .whl file I was able to successfully install was using:

```
pip install lxml-4.0.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

However, I still get the import etree error with this version.  So I tried other versions of lxml, but still get the error "Is not a supported wheel on this platform" for the following files:

```
pip install lxml-3.8.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
pip install lxml-3.8.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
pip install lxml-4.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
pip install lxml-3.8.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl
pip install lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
```

I am confused why this is not working.

Comment: For what it's worth - I've read about 32/64 bit incompatibility and after checking my system settings, it appears I have a 64 bit operating system.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove or rename the `lxml` directory in the `L:\Code\Scripts` directory.