# Which platform to use when importing Python Packages into the Azure Automation engine

Tags: python, azure, automation

I have a Python script that I want to run in the Azure Automation engine.  It imports a few packages, one of which is [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/#files).  There are a lot of platform variations available from the Python Package Index and I can't find any documentation from Azure about which platform I should be using.

Choosing the wrong version provides the following error through the Azure portal:

```
Orchestrator.Activities.PythonPackageExtractException: Error while extractinig Python package: Unexpected file structure in .whl file for python package lxml. It is likely that the package is for an unsupported platform. 
    at Orchestrator.Activities.SetModuleActivity.ExecuteInternal(CodeActivityContext context, Byte[] moduleContent, String moduleName, ModuleLanguage moduleLanguage, Guid moduleVersionId, String modulePath) 
    at Orchestrator.Activities.SetModuleActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) 
    at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
    at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I'm not the only one who's had trouble figuring out which version / platform to use for setting up lxml.  Based on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454548/trouble-installing-correct-version-of-lxml-with-updated-context), I tried running the following in the Automation environment:

```
import platform
print(platform.architecture())
```

This gave me the result `('64bit', 'WindowsPE')`, which was enough to guess that I needed the library with `win_amd64.whl` as the postfix.  Sure enough, that worked.

So, if you're importing libraries into the Azure Automation engine, make sure they're tagged as `cp27` and made for the `win_amd64` platform.

Answer (score 0):

Wheels must be downloaded from pypi.org.

For runbooks created in Python 3.8, search for wheels: packagename_*cp38*_*amd64*

For runbooks created in Python 3.10, search for wheels: packagename_*cp310*_*amd64*

More details [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/automation/python-3-packages.md#packages-as-source-files)

In your case you should use this one:
[lxml in pypi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuItg.png)